# Why is the number of black nodes in a Red-Black tree at least ⌈h/2⌉?

Tags: trees, data-structure

Why is the number of black nodes in a Red-Black tree at least ⌈h/2⌉ where h is the tree height?

Wikipedia Red-black tree [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to try to answer your question since the question itself seems to indicate that you don't at all understand the nature of this data structure.

Comment: Do you know how to construct a red-black tree? Its construction is designed this way so that search is guaranteed to have time complexity $O(\lg(n))$. It's essentially a clever implementation of a balanced search tree.

Comment: Yes, but knowing that doesn't help me understand why the number of black nodes in a Red-Black tree is at least ⌈h/2⌉.

Comment: It might if you sharpened your pencil and wrote down some examples to see how they work. The formulas don't come from separate principle. They are a codification of the insight into how these data structures are built.

Comment: Yes, but I want to prove it algebraically. I know that two red nodes cannot appear one after another, so a black node must separate them, and so it makes sense that the black height is at least h/2. But I would be glad if someone can enlighten me on how that helps me to answer the question above.

Comment: Try using induction on the height of the tree. As it stands, this question shows no effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essence is the third property: a red node can't have a red child (*red rule*). Take a path from the root to a NIL vertex. This is a chain of father-son $v_1, \ldots, v_h$, with $v_1$ being the root, $h$ being the height of the tree, $v_h$ being a NIL node (a leaf). Just to simplify the explanation, let us distinguish in two cases: $h$ is odd and $h$ is even.

If $h=2m$, suppose by contradiction that there are at least $m+1$ red nodes in the chain. Since if you alternate black and red you fit at most $m$ red nodes, there should be two red nodes one after another, in contradiction with the red rule. We conclude there are at most $m$ red nodes, that is at least $m = h/2$ black nodes.

If $h=2m+1$, suppose there are at least $m+1$ red nodes. The only way you can do this without having two consecutive red nodes is by starting coloring $v_1$ with red, alternating, and finishing $v_h$ with red. But this contradicts the NIL rule, since $v_h$ must be black. We conclude that there are at most $m$ red nodes, that is at least $m+1 = \left  \lceil \frac{h}{2} \right \rceil$ nodes.